# Redirecting stderr to stdout in subprocess.check_output does not print out the error message. Why?

Tags: python, subprocess

I am calling a shell command from python's subprocess module, using check_output.

As shown below, I try to get the error message of executing a wrong shell command `lsl -l`, by redirecting stderr to stdout. But it does not work apparently. Why?

```
In [5]: subprocess.check_output("lsl -l", shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)                                             
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
CalledProcessError                        Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-5-8dd15c76eb0f> in <module>
----> 1 subprocess.check_output("lsl -l", shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)

/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in check_output(timeout, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    624 
    625     return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
--> 626                **kwargs).stdout
    627 
    628 

/usr/lib/python3.5/subprocess.py in run(input, timeout, check, *popenargs, **kwargs)
    706         if check and retcode:
    707             raise CalledProcessError(retcode, process.args,
--> 708                                      output=stdout, stderr=stderr)
    709     return CompletedProcess(process.args, retcode, stdout, stderr)
    710 

CalledProcessError: Command 'lsl -l' returned non-zero exit status 127
```

Answer (score 0):

You should try using **;exit 0;** after your command. Documentation for check_output itself says that it raises **CalledProcessError** if the process exits with Non zero status. Refer [check_output](https://docs.python.org/3/library/subprocess.html#subprocess.check_output) for more details. Try the below command:

```
subprocess.check_output("lsl -l;exit 0;", shell=True,stderr=subprocess.STDOUT)
```

Comment: Thanks. But it does not look like a robust solution to me. With 'exit 0', one would not even know that the command fails (unless the error message is to be read manually).